# Explaining LCM intuitively

Tags: education, gcd-and-lcm

Here's the approach that I use when trying to find LCM.

$18 = 2\times3\times 3$

$12 = 2\times 2\times 3$

To be a multiple of 18 a number must have prime factors of at least one $2$ and two $3$.

To be a multiple of 12 a number must have prime factors of at least two $2$ and one $3$.

Hence the number with at least two $2$ and two $3$ prime factors will be the lowest number that is a common multiple of both $18$ and $12$.

Therefore, $2\times 2\times 3\times 3=36$ is the lowest common multiple of $12$ and $18$.

---

Would it be correct to 'expand' this a bit more like this in order to explain the above to someone:

> To be a multiple of 18 a number must have prime factors of at least
> one $2$ and two $3$.
>
> To be a multiple of 12 a number must have prime factors of at least
> two $2$ and one $3$.

Let's say the LCM of $12$ and $18$ is $x$

We know that a multiple of $12$ and $18$ is $12\times 18$

Which in prime factor form is: $2\times3\times 3 \times 2\times 2\times 3$

Let's say that this is the LCM we know of the two numbers so far, therefore:

$x =2\times3\times 3 \times 2\times 2\times 3$

We know that the minimum number of $2$'s required to be a multiple of both $12$ and $18$ is two. So let's cut off any extra $2$'s present in our LCM $x$:

$x =2\times3\times 3 \times 2\times$ <s>2</s> $\times 3$

We know that the minimum number of $3$'s required to be a multiple of both $12$ and $18$ is two. So let's cut off any extra $3$'s present in our LCM $x$:

$x =2\times3\times 3 \times 2\times$ <s>2</s> $\times$ <s>3</s>

Hence our LCM $x$ has now been updated to:

$x =2\times3\times 3 \times 2$

Resulting in $x=2\times 2\times 3\times 3=36$

Comment: Personally, I prefer the formula $\displaystyle \text{lcm}(a,b) = \frac{a \times b}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}.$  My thinking is that gcd$(a,b)$ represents the **redundant** factor that is being over-applied, and thus shows in the denominator as a *correction-factor*.

Comment: Another way to think about it is the lcm takes the maximum of the exponents of the prime factors (gcd takes the minimum), for instance $\mathrm{lcm}(18,12)=\mathrm{lcm}(2^13^2,2^23^1) = 2^{\max(1,2)}3^{\max(2,1)}=2^23^2=36$.